# converting the date from String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my code I am getting a string from server the value is "06-27-2014", Then I want to convert to other date format but the final result i am getting is very different. Here is the code am using.

```
        NSString* dateVal = @"06-27-2014";

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy"];
        NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtZone];

        NSDate* aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:**dateVal**];
           I am getting the aDate as **2014-01-26 18:36:00 +0000** here the month is completely changing to first month from 6th. 

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        NSDate *theDateSelected =aDate;

        NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theDateSelected];
```

The Final date i am getting is ***27/01/14*** which is totally different Can any one suggest the correct date format.

Comment: What is the preferred format? You haven't mentioned it.
Also, why would you use `**...**` for naming an `NSString`?

Comment: *** NSString* **dateVal** = @"06-27-2014"; *** its not in a proper format..

Answer (score 5):

Your date format is wrong, it should be `MM` for month. `mm` is used for minutes.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy"];
```

should be

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, seems like your date formatter value is wrong.

```
    NSString* dateVal = @"06-27-2014";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtZone];

    NSDate* aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateVal];// Now here you will get date like "06-27-2014", and mm is for minutes, you should use MM for month.

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSDate *theDateSelected =aDate;

    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theDateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is wrong.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
```

m is for minute,
M is for month.

Always chek the [date format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) reference ;-)